# How can I always run a command automatically after doing rlogin to a remote server?

Tags: linux, bash

I use my script when connecting to a remote server.

```
#!/bin/bash

host=$1
root=$2


case "$host" in
  "1" ) host="server1";;
  "2" ) host="server2";;
esac


if [ -z "$root" ];then
  rlogin -l user $host 
else
  rlogin -l root $host
fi
```

Something like this.

What I want more is to run `PS1="\[\e[34;1m\]\u@\[\e[36;1m\]\h:\[\e[32;1m\]\w:> \[\e[0m\]"` after connecting to the remote server, which makes the terminal visually good.

Editting `.bashrc` cannot be done because this remote server is used my multiple users.

I tried

```
rlogin -l user $host && PS1="\[\e[34;1m\]\u@\[\e[36;1m\]\h:\[\e[32;1m\]\w:> \[\e[0m\]"
```

but this didn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What I do in this situation is create a function on the remote machine. This function sets the shell to my liking. So I log in, execute my function, and then I'm ready to go.

Comment: Whoa, it's like 30 years since every one else stopped using `rlogin` and switched to `ssh`. You too might want to take the plunge one of these decades.

Comment: Having a script supply some input to `rlogin` (or `ssh`, or `telnet`, or etc) but then switching to an interactive session is not an uncomplicated problem. `expect` can do this rather elegantly.